# Mongo GridFS How to delete files older than a given date?

Tags: mongodb, gridfs

I came by this problem on how to delete files older than a certain date and couldn't find a quick answer on the web, so here I'm posting the question and answering it, hopefully it'll save someone 15 minutes at some point.

Essentially I wanted to have the behavior of the following command (delete files older than five days) kind thing

```
find /path/to/files* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

but in mongo.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
db.fs.files.remove({"uploadDate": {$lt : ISODate("2013-11-10T20:32:13.743Z")}});
```

Comment: This only works if you have the 'uploadDate' in your document, so it is a not a solution for everyone.

Comment: I believe GridFS supplies this for you http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/gridfs/

Comment: GridFS is storing the file content in the "fs.chunks" collection. So you'll leave the actual data when only removing the "fs.files" entry.

Comment: As @Oskar says, you would need to delete the related files from `fs.chunks` collection. As you are only deleting the metadata/references.

e.g. as described [here](https://gist.github.com/xelaz/8aceeacc6306c5dd92f2c91699d89a27)

Answer (score 2):

Removing data from fs.files is not a good solution. You should always retreive the file_id from the fs.files and use the grid fs object to remove the same